# How to redirect back in Inertia.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, inertiajs

I have a page that can be accessed from multiple pages. Is it possible to redirect back and preserve the state? I'm using Laravel + Inertia.js.

something like

```
this.$inertia.visit(route().back(), {preserveState: true});
```

Comment: Just do it `return redirect()->back();` in you controller.

Answer (score 2):

I go back from a page in Inertia by calling

```
window.history.back()
```

Works great for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple method of laravel when you want to access to a route

```
return redirect()->route('route_name');
```

> Or when you want to return to the previous router use

```
return back();
```

Answer (score 0):

The history.back() works perfectly and preserves state. Use

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.back()">mylink</a>
```